# Replace periods and commas with space in each file within the folder then print files

Tags: python

I have a folder with a bunch of files, and each file contains a text string, periods, and commas. I want to replace periods and commas with spaces and print all files afterwards.

But after replacing the commas and dots with blanks and printing the files, the thing in the image is printed, and I do not want to print the dots and commas, I want to print the files after replacing the commas and the dots in them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGvA6.png)

```
def read_corpus_file_and_delete_stop_words():
    stop_words_list = stopwords.words('english')
    additional_stopwords = []

    with open("C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/IR Homework/stop words.txt", 'r') as file:
        for word in file:
            word = word.split('\n')
            additional_stopwords.append(word[0])

    stop_words_list += additional_stopwords

    dir_path = 'C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/corpus/'
    save_dir = "C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Files_Without_SW/"

    files_without_sw = []
    for document in os.listdir(dir_path):
        with open(dir_path + document, "r") as reader:
            save_file = open(save_dir + document, 'w')
            text = reader.read()

            text = text.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', ' ')

            text = text.replace('  ', ' ')  # convert double space into single space
            text = text.strip()  # remove space at the end

            # text_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
            tokens_without_sw = [word for word in text.split(' ') if
                                 (word not in stop_words_list)]
            # save_file.writelines(["%s " % item for item in tokens_without_sw])
            # print(document, ':', tokens_without_sw)
            files_without_sw.append(tokens_without_sw)
    return files_without_sw
```

Comment: you print `tokens_without_sw` but you should print `filtered_sentences`

Comment: if `text` is string then `for word in text` splits it into single chars, not words. You would use `text.split(' ')` to split into words. But first you should replace commas and dots. Code `[word for word in "Hello World"]` gives `['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']`, not `["Hello", "World"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is not `replace` but `for word in text` which split into chars, not words.

This code

```
stopwords = ['and', 'or']

text = "Hello World. Bye."
tokens_without_sw = [word for word in text if word not in stopwords]
print(tokens_without_sw)
```

gives

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '.', ' ', 'B', 'y', 'e', '.']
```

but you expected `["Hello", "World.", "Bye."]`

You shoudl use `text.split(" ")` to get words - but first you should replace `commas` and `dots` because you may have text without spaces like `"World.Bye"` and then it will treat it as single word. Besides if you don't replace `commas` and `dots` before removing `stop_words_list` then it may keep stopwords with `dots` or `commas` - like `or...`

```
stopwords = ['and', 'or']

text = "Hello World. Bye."

text = text.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', ' ')

text = text.replace('  ', ' ')  # convert double space into single space

text = text.strip()  # remove space at the end

tokens_without_sw = [word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stopwords]

print(tokens_without_sw)
```

Result:

```
['Hello', 'World', 'Bye']
```

---

Example with `or...` and with `regex` to remove more then two spaces.

```
import re

stopwords = ['and', 'or']

text = "Hello World. or... Bye."

text = text.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', ' ')
#text = re.sub('\.|,', ' ', text)

#text = text.replace('  ', ' ')  # convert double space into single space
text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text)  # convert many spaces into single space

text = text.strip()  # remove space at the end

tokens_without_sw = [word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stopwords]

print(tokens_without_sw)
```

Comment: I modified my code in the same way that you modified the code, but I have a problem, which is that the elements are printed within 2list, like:=> [[elements]]........

How can i solve the problem? @furas

Comment: it seems you have nested lists and you should get `list[0]` to have only `[elements]` OR if you have `[[elements], [elements]` then you should use `for`-loop like `for item in list: print(item)`